# Error in ubuntu 14 lts "unknown tools version 14 in monodevelop". How to install tools version 14 in monodevelop?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I developed a C# project in Visual Studio Community 2015. I am trying to open the solution in Ubuntu 14 LTS. I am using Mono-Develop 4. Whenever I try to open the solution it displays an error as follows : "Unknown Tools version 14".

Comment: please upgrade MonoDevelop to v5.x

Comment: @knocte I tried but it says that I have the latest version of mono develop. I also tried to install it from the git but no luck.

Comment: `no luck` is not enough information, if you have trouble compiling monodevelop from git, please post the problem in a new stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop probably hasn't gotten around to supporting version 14.  Sometimes it takes them a while.

To fix this issue (not a great way in my opinion, but it works), is to vim into your .csproj file, and change `ToolsVersion="14.0"` to `ToolsVersion="4.0"`

This seems really hacky, but it seems to work for me.  Then you may hit the `Framework'.NETFramework 4.5.2' not installed.`

Not sure how to get through this one yet.  I'll update if I figure it out.